# Smell of Ammonia when driving. What can be the reason?

Tags: exhaust, smell, infiniti, g35

I started smelling ammonia when a drive.  What can be the reason?

I did recently changed the exhaust pipe.  I drive infinity G35.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you changed the cabin filters lately?

Black mold can smell like Urine-Ammonia, this mold can also grow on the ac evaporator coil.

Pull the cabin filters and check for mold.

Other than this it could be a rich running engine that causes the catalytic converter to put out strong odors.